# Github action to surf a page

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to deploy my github project to a host. I followed some Actions like FTP-DEPLOY-ACTION, but it sometimes fail because of dns or network error.

As solution I cloned the project on the host, then I created a page on the site like:

```
import git
@blueprint.route('/pull', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pull():
    g = git.cmd.Git("~/folder")
    msg = g.pull()
    return msg
```

It seems working by surfing the page on browser. I would like to know if I can call the page via a github action so it happens automatically after each push?

Comment: You mean like `curl yourwebsite.com/pull`? Or what type of "call" did you have in mind?

Comment: @rethab maybe curl works, I want it makes the code behind page be executed (the pull). Then the action returns success

Comment: Please give curl a try and report back :)